# Keep class "implements" when Proguard obfuscating

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation

My problem is a class definition is changed after Proguard **obfuscation** is run 
(Mind it is not changed when -dontobfuscate turned on!).

```
package com.google.ads.mediation.inmobi;

...
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
import com.google.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest;
import com.google.ads.mediation.MediationBannerAdapter;
import com.google.ads.mediation.MediationBannerListener;
import com.google.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialAdapter;
import com.google.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener;
import com.google.ads.mediation.inmobi.InMobiAdapterExtras;
import com.google.ads.mediation.inmobi.InMobiAdapterServerParameters;
import com.inmobi.commons.AnimationType;
import com.inmobi.commons.GenderType;
import com.inmobi.commons.InMobi;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMBanner;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMBannerListener;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMErrorCode;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMIncentivisedListener;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMInterstitial;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMInterstitialListener;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMInterstitial.State;
...

public final class InMobiAdapter implements MediationInterstitialAdapter<InMobiAdapterExtras, InMobiAdapterServerParameters>, MediationBannerAdapter<InMobiAdapterExtras, InMobiAdapterServerParameters> {
```

is turned into:

```
package com.google.ads.mediation.inmobi;

...
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
import com.google.ads.mediation.MediationAdRequest;
import com.google.ads.mediation.MediationBannerListener;
import com.google.ads.mediation.MediationInterstitialListener;
import com.google.ads.mediation.inmobi.InMobiAdapterExtras;
import com.google.ads.mediation.inmobi.InMobiAdapterServerParameters;
import com.inmobi.commons.AnimationType;
import com.inmobi.commons.GenderType;
import com.inmobi.commons.InMobi;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMBanner;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMBannerListener;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMErrorCode;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMIncentivisedListener;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMInterstitial;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMInterstitialListener;
import com.inmobi.monetization.IMInterstitial.State;
...

public final class InMobiAdapter {
```

My proguard settings are below so I that is why the code of InmobiAdapter class is not obfuscated. However my **MediationInterstitialAdapter interface etc are thrown out** from there:

```
> -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
> -optimizationpasses 3
> -allowaccessmodification
...
>  -keep class com.google.** { *; }
```

What should I set to keep that **"implements ..."** part

Answer (score 0):

Do this for all your interface

```
-keep interface com.google.ads.mediation.MediationBannerAdapter{
&lt;methods&gt;;}
```